# Isotopy classes of torus embeddings in $S^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

How do we describe the (ambient) isotopy classes of embeddings $T^2 \to S^3$ of the torus to the $3$-sphere? We can get examples from thickening knots, but there is also an additional piece of information from twists in the thickening (if we talk about ambient isotopy). Is this a classification?

Naively, the main problem comes from the fact that there seems to be no way to canonically "unthicken" a torus embedding

Comment: What equivalence relation are you using? Your words regarding "twists in the thickening" lead me to think your intention is isotopy of the functions themselves that define the embedding, as opposed to isotopy of the image subset of the function.

Comment: @LeeMosher If I understand whats going on, isotopy of the functions that define the embedding means that the twists matter, whereas isotopy of the image subset would lose this information - if that's all the difference there is, then I would be interested in learning about either situation; if it's more complicated then that, I'm not sure what the 'right' question to ask is

Comment: For a related discussion of that distinction, in the case of knots themselves, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063472/equivalence-of-unoriented-knots-by-ambient-isotopy?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can understand all isotopy classes of images of tori as boundaries of thickened knots.  This is because of the [loop theorem](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Edannyc/courses/3manifolds_2014/3_manifolds_notes.pdf): the induced map $\pi_1(T^2)\to\pi_1(S^3)$ has nontrivial kernel, so there is an embedded disk in the complement of the image of the torus that meets the torus transversely along its boundary, and the boundary represents a nontrivial homotopy class.  We can [compress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompressible_surface) the torus along the disk to get a sphere, and by the 3D Schoenflies theorem this sphere bounds a ball on both sides.  One of the two balls is on the other side of the sphere from the compression disk, and then by thickening the disk we can construct a solid torus whose boundary is the original torus.  Therefore, there is an embedded circle $K\subset S^3$ such that the torus is the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of $K$.

This gives a (mostly) canonical coordinate system for the torus, at least when $K$ is not an unknot, i.e. a boundary of an embedded disk, by the following.  Give $K$ an arbitrary orientation. Exactly one side of the torus is a solid torus, call it $S\subset S^3$, and let $C\subset S^3$ be the complement of the closure of $S$.  The induced map $H_1(T)\to H_1(C)$ has kernel $\mathbb{Z}$, and a generator can be represented by an isotopy class $\lambda\in T$ of an oriented simple closed curve called the *longitude*.  There are two choices of orientation, but we may choose the one that coincides with $K$ when it is included in $H_1(S)$.  The induced map $H_1(T)\to H_1(S)$ has kernel isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, and a generator can be represented by an oriented simple closed curve $\mu\subset T$ called a *meridian*.  Again, there are two choices of orientation, but we may choose the one such that the algebraic intersection number of $\mu$ and $\lambda$ with respect to the induced orientation of $\partial S$ is $1$ (this makes $\mu$ loop around $K$ according to the right-hand rule).

The torus $T^2$ has a natural basis $(\alpha,\beta)$ via the generators of $H_1(T)$ coming from the two $S^1$ factors (since $T=S^1\times S^1$).  So the embedding up to isotopy can be represented by the following data: (1) the isotopy class of the oriented knot $K$ and (2) the $2\times 2$ basis change matrix on $H_1(T)$ between the $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $(\mu,\lambda)$ bases of $H_1(T)$, since diffeomorphisms $T\to T$ up to isotopy are classified by their induced map on $H_1(T)$.

**However:** This is not yet a classification.  There are two issues.

1. We had to make a choice for the orientation of $K$.  Switching the orientation of $K$ has the effect of $(\mu,\lambda)\leftrightarrow (-\mu,-\lambda)$, so we need to simultaneously perform the same action to the basis change matrix (which amounts to negation).
2. The knot $K$ might be an unknot.  In this case, both $S$ and $C$ are solid tori, so it could be described by the knot in the core of $C$ as well.  However, [there is an isotopy carrying the torus to itself](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Clifford-torus.gif) while carrying the unknot in $C$ to $K$.  This has the effect of swapping $\mu$ and $\lambda$, so you can just take the matrix up to this additional move.

Taking these issues into consideration, we get a complete classification of embeddings $T^2\to S^3$ up to isotopy.

*Aside:* If $K$ is not the unknot, then a simple invariant is the determinant of the basis change matrix, which is $\pm 1$ depending on whether the orientation of the image of $T^2$ coincides with the induced orientation of $\partial S$.

---

One piece in more detail: $\lambda$ gives the canonical "$0$-framing" of $K$.  This is the piece of information that gives a canonical identification of a solid torus with a tubular neighborhood of $K$.  If what you care about is embeddings of solid tori in $S^3$, then the amount of twist can be recorded relative to the $0$-framing as an integer $n$.  In particular, the solid torus comes with its own longitude, which will equal $\pm(n\mu+\lambda)$.  Embeddings of solid tori up to isotopy are classified by the pair $(K, n)$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I wonder now what this says about the higher-genus case, in particular if I have an embedded genus 2 surface, it seems I can use the loop theorem to get a nontrivial loop, which I can compress to get an embedded torus, which looks like a tubular neighborhood of a knot. So I'd like to say that the 'core' of the g=2 surface is the knot plus a line transverse to the disc that we compressed (this 'core' topologically is wedge of two circles) - is this sensible? One problem is that I don't really know precisely how to define tubular neighborhod of a wedge of two circles?

Comment: @JoshuaLin Higher genus surfaces unfortunately get more complicated! The issue is that the compression disks might be on opposite sides of the surface, or they might even have intersecting thickenings.  In the simplest case, you get a generalization of a solid torus, a *handlebody* (a thickened-up wedge of circles).  It looks like general surfaces were recently studied in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05030